# Can snow chains for passenger tires be used on light truck tires?

Tags: tires, van, snow-chain

I was looking for snow chains to fit some LT215/75R15 tires that are on a van (which has clearance for chains). I obtained some snow chains that fit (among other sizes) P215/75R15 tires. Does the tire type matter? Will snow chains for passenger tires work without issue on light truck tires?

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference in size between LT215/75R15 and P215/75R15.  They should fit and work just fine.